# How to use jquery cycle 2 continuous slider but more than one image?

Tags: jquery-cycle2

I am using jquery cycle 2 to get a continuous slideshow effect...http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/continuous.php

Here is code:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow cycle-autoinit"
        data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz"
        data-cycle-slides="> div"
        data-cycle-speed="3000"
        data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true"
        data-cycle-timeout="1"
        data-cycle-easing="linear"
        data-cycle-carousel-visible=5>

       <div>
         <a href="@slide.Link" target="_blank">
           <img src="@Url.Content("~/content/cms/slideshow/")@slide.ImageName" alt="" /></a>
       </div> 
  <div>
         <a href="@slide.Link" target="_blank">
           <img src="@Url.Content("~/content/cms/slideshow/")@slide.ImageName" alt="" /></a>
       </div>                            
    </div>
```

This works. However only one image slides across the screen and then the next appears. What i want is all images slides across next to each other so like 5 are appearing and going round on a rotation?

Comment: did you figure this out? If so can you post solution? Thks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of what you want if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/CersX/2/

I basically added `data-cycle-carousel-fluid=true` `data-cycle-easing="linear"` to there example.

Just swap out the images for yours.

> I based my code from http://codepen.io/colir/pen/bhcAx

Answer (score 2):

Hi I think you have to set your data-cycle-fx=carousel.
Try this:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow cycle-autoinit"
    data-cycle-fx="carousel"
    data-cycle-slides="> div"
    data-cycle-speed="3000"
    data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true"
    data-cycle-timeout="1"
    data-cycle-easing="linear"
    data-cycle-carousel-visible=5>

...
```

I can't test it now but I hope it works.

> Cycle2's [carousel transition plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/download/) must be included in order to use the carousel effect.

Comment: Added a downloadlink

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer - 
[carousel-slide-dimension on Jquery Cycle2 -fixed width/height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914587/carousel-slide-dimension-on-jquery-cycle2-fixed-width-height)

'**carouselSlideDimension**' as your argument or:

data-cycle-carousel-slide-dimension=ANUMBER

```
$this.cycle({
 "allowWrap" : false,
 "carouselSlideDimension" : "151px",
 "carouselVisible" : 3,
 "fx" : "carousel",
 "log" : false,
 "timeout" : 0,
 "next" : "#" + id + " .next",
 "prev" : "#" + id + " .prev",
 "slideActiveClass" : "active",
 "slides" : "> .slide",
});
```